# Moment of inertia of disk with off center hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

So I am given the figure shown below and told to find the moment of inertia if we have that the mass of the shaded region is $M$. I think I have to find the total mass without the hole and the mass taken away for the hole and then subtract the moment of inertia of $r$ from the moment of inertia of $R$ using parallel axis theorem. I have no idea how to find the total mass however and am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

[image: fig1]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: Density is an intrinsic property of a body.It is independent of how much of the material is present and is independent of the form of the material, e.g., one large piece or a collection of small particles.

Here the mass is based on ***area*** of the disc and not the volume.
  
Let the density of the disc be equal to $d$.
Then, Mass of total disc initially is
$$
M_T=\pi R^2 d\\
$$

Mass Removed is,
$$
m=\pi r^2 d\\
$$
We also have,
$$
M=\pi (R^2-r^2)d
$$
Therefore,
$$
M_T=\frac{M\pi R^2}{\pi(R^2-r^2)}
$$